# Echo short code syntax

Tags: php, shortcode

I want to make dynamic short code so insert php code of metabox text value to short code.

I wrote this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[svg-flag flag=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ozellikler_text', true);".\"]"); ?>
```

Error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in /home/deniztas/themeforest-deneme2.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/my_homepages/right.php on line 14
```

I explain what I want step by step:

There is a short code which shows country flags.

```
[svg-flag flag="tr"]
```

For example, this code shows Turkey (tr) flag.

I want to change the `"tr"`to dynamic metabox text value:

```
<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ozellikler_text', true) ?>
```

How can I do it? What is true syntax or simpler way than mine?

I ask this here instead of stackoverflow because I think maybe it needs wordpress info.**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is saying to change `;` to `.` - you will also want to remove the extra `.`:

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode("[svg-flag flag=\""  . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ozellikler_text', true) . "\"]"); ?>
```